# How to fix type error using tensorflow data API for rejection sampling

Tags: python, tensorflow, types, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I am using the tensorflow data API to try and do some rejection sampling for my unbalanced data set.

I have run the code on my personal computer and it seems to work as I expect it to, however, when I run the code on my University's cluster I get a type error that I can't seem to understand. I have tried recasting and I get the same error.

I am still learning how to use this API and I'm still not 100% clear on if this is the best way to achieve what I want, so I also welcome any advice on how I implemented the rejection sampling (this could very well be the reason why I get error since I don't fully understand yet).

This is how I am loading in the data to the dataset:

```
data = np.loadtxt("my_data.dat")
features = data[:, 1:10]
labels = data[:, 0]
labels[labels == -1] = 0
assert features.shape[0] == labels.shape[0]
dataset_size = len(features)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features.astype('float32'),
                                                   labels.astype('int32')))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=dataset_size)
```

the error occurs when I read here:

```
train_size = int((2/3.0)*dataset_size)
tr_dataset = dataset.take(train_size)
tr_dataset = (tr_dataset.apply(
    tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample(
        class_func=lambda _, c: c, target_dist=[0.5, 0.5],
        seed=42)).map(lambda a, b: b)).batch(100)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 510, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1094, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 931, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype int64: 'Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 185, in <module>
    seed=42))).batch(100)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1109, in apply
    dataset = transformation_func(self)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/resampling.py", line 74, in _apply_fn
    target_dist_t, class_values_ds)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/resampling.py", line 183, in _estimate_initial_dist_ds
    update_estimate_and_tile))
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1109, in apply
    dataset = transformation_func(self)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/scan_ops.py", line 172, in _apply_fn
    return _ScanDataset(dataset, initial_state, scan_func)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/scan_ops.py", line 74, in __init__
    add_to_graph=False)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1459, in __init__
    self._function._create_definition_if_needed()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 337, in _create_definition_if_needed
    self._create_definition_if_needed_impl()
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 346, in _create_definition_if_needed_impl
    self._capture_by_value, self._caller_device)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 863, in func_graph_from_py_func
    outputs = func(*func_graph.inputs)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1392, in tf_data_structured_function_wrapper
    ret = func(*nested_args)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/resampling.py", line 176, in update_estimate_and_tile
    c, num_examples_per_class_seen)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/resampling.py", line 212, in _estimate_data_distribution
    array_ops.one_hot(c, num_classes, dtype=dtypes.int64), 0))
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 297, in add
    "Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflowcpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 546, in _apply_op_helper
    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Add' Op has type int64 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

Comment: Does the versions of tf differ from your local and your cluster? And from line 176 and 212 of resample.py pointed out in your error trace, I think converting to int32 is the problem for the second exception.

Comment: @kvish Yes, on my local its 1.13 and on my cluster its 1.10. I have tried not casting and I get the error that the only supported types are uint8, int32, int64. I have tried using the "other" supported types and I get the same error as in the post. I don't really know where to go from here

Comment: UPDATE: I have upgraded the tensorflow version on the cluster to 1.13 (the version on my local machine) and I get the same error...

Comment: this is very weird. Could this be an issue in the sense that you might need to pass dtype compatible with numpy or tf? As in you can use [tf.cast](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/cast) to cast your data types, or use np.int32 etc?